# Get newest object added to NSFetchedResultsController?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Not even sure if this is feasible, but here's the use case:

I have a RootView tableview that uses `NSFetchedResultsController` to manage the list. I tap an add button, which presents the `AdditionViewController`. The `AdditionViewController` uses a separate`managedObjectContext` to create the new object. On Save, the object is passed back to the RootView, where the new object (in the new `managedObjectContext`) is merged into the main `managedObjectContext`. The `AdditionViewController` is then dismissed, revealing the RootView.

What I would *like* to do, is to push my `DetailViewController` with the new object loaded after the merge, so that when the `AdditionViewController` is dismissed, the full detail view is revealed.

How can I get the object that has just been added to the `fetchedResultsController` in order to pass it to the `DetailViewController`?

### --UPDATE--

Still nothing on this. Let me try to explain what I need to do (hopefully) a bit better. If this is still confusing, ask questions. I'm having a hard time thinking of how to describe the problem.

I am fully aware how to push the Detail view underneath the modal addition view upon saving the new object.  The problem is that the object I am saving is in its own `fetchedReaultsController`. I am merging this frc into the main `fetchedResultsController`, so if I try to sent the object to the detailview, I get a crash, because the object has been invalidated (due to the merge) by the time the modal addition view is dismissed, and the detailview calls `viewWillAppear`. That is what I am trying to get around. How can I figure out what object was just added to the main `fetchedResultsController` in order to send it to the detailViewController?

### --UPDATE--

Adding a bounty for anyone who can tell me how to retrieve the most recently added object from a fetched results controller. Or how to retrieve a specific object from a fetched results controller without knowing it's indexPath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record, the answer was to grab the object ID of the object in the addingManagedObjectContext AFTER saving the context (since the ID changes after saving), and passing that ID to the main managedObjectContext after the merge. The full code required for this is below (if anyone has an easier way, let me know)

```
detailViewController.object = (customObject *)[[fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext] objectWithID:[[[[addingManagedObjectContext registeredObjects] allObjects] objectAtIndex:0] objectID]];
```

Thanks to [frenetisch applaudierend](https://stackoverflow.com/users/188461/frenetisch-applaudierend) for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it in an almost identical use case:

1. While the `AdditionViewController` is displayed, the user has the option of saving the item they created or cancelling out of the new item dialog. I communicated the user's choice back to the `RootViewController`.
2. If the user cancelled, remove the object you created from your context.
3. If the user chose to save, save the context and display the `DetailViewController`.

Comment: Yeah, I can get that to work. I already have a save bool implemented. What I can't figure out is how to get the object that was just saved in order to pass it to the `DetailViewController`.

Comment: how are you creating the managed object before you save it? Just hold a reference to it and pass it back to the delegate.

Comment: I can do that too, but it's in a different managed context. So by the time the detailview is shown, the object has become invalidated due to the merge.

Comment: You could pass back the object ID instead of the whole object and then refetch it in the new context.